# CodeIgniter 3 is_unique validation when table name have dot a "."

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Im having a problem with Codeigniter 3 if i have a table called "dbo.Usuarios" how i can insert in is_unique validation? The problem its that is_unique separe te table and column with a dot.

Here is the problem :

```php
$is_unique =  '|is_unique[dbo.Usuarios.Email]';
```

How you can see, my table name have a dot so the system take **"dbo"** like table name and **"Usuarios"** like colum name.

And here the full code:

```
$id= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $tablas = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM dbo.Usuarios WHERE ID ='.$id.'');
    foreach ($tablas->result_array() as $row){
    $samemail = $row['Email'];    
    }
    if($this->input->post('email') != $samemail) {
    $is_unique =  '|is_unique[dbo.Usuarios.Email]';
    } 
    else {
   $is_unique =  '';
    }    

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailf', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|max_length[20]'.$is_unique);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('emailunico', 'El Email ingresado ya esta asociado a otra cuenta.');
    redirect('escritorio');  
    }
    else {
    #othercode
    }
```

Comment: why are you using `dbo.` as a prefix?

Comment: You shouldn't really use `.` within table names. Standard advice would be to use unserscores `_` instead as the period is interpreted as the "boundary" between schema and table names. Having said that, the `is_unique` validation method doesn't support a `schema.table.field` argument (it expects just a table-field pair), so you'd need to modify or extend the `form_validation` library to work for you

Comment: For the record, i decided to use dbo. as prefix, thanks for the suggestion @M.Hemant

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the `is_unique` rule like this :

```php
$is_unique =  '|is_unique[dbo.Email]|is_unique[Usuarios.Email]';
```